# Check if a string consists of letters and symbols using regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am implementing a validation in a setter method in Java to check if a user enters a string value that only consists of letters and optionally currency symbols. There should be spaces between words or symbols if the user wants to include more than one value. The input is inserted via the scanner, and I am trying the regex below, but it is taking the first word of the whole line, ignoring the remaining words. I need to take all the words in the line before setting it to my private variable.

If there is a simple way other than the regex, please also note it.

```
public void set(String countryCurrency) {
    if(countryCurrency.matches("^[a-zA-Z\\p{Sc}]*$")) {
        this.currency = countryCurrency;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the value is not the whole line, the problem may com the scanner reading, not here. Please share the scnning code

Comment: Perhaps you could add a log statement `System.out.println(countryCurrency);` and show us what the input is.

Comment: When I print the countryCurrency to the console, it only takes the first word, ignoring the other words.

Comment: Please provide an example of input with multiple valid values.  Are all of them assigned to `currency`?

Answer (score 0):

> The input is inserted via the scanner, and I am trying the regex
> below, but it isn't taking the whole line, ignoring the remaining
> part.

It happens when you use [`Scanner#next`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) instead of [`Scanner#nextLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()). Note that `Scanner#next` stops scanning as soon as it encounters whitespace in your input.

As per your requirement, you also need to change your regex as shown below:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("abc $".matches("((\\p{Sc}\\s+)?\\p{Alpha}(\\s+\\p{Sc})?)+"));
        System.out.println("$ abc".matches("((\\p{Sc}\\s+)?\\p{Alpha}(\\s+\\p{Sc})?)+"));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
true
```

**Explanation of the regex:**

1. `(\\p{Sc}\\s+)?` specifies optional (currency symbol followed by whitespace).
2. `\\p{Alpha}` specifies alphabets.
3. `(\\s+\\p{Sc})?` specifies optional (whitespace followed by currency symbol).

Comment: When I change `Scanner.next` to `Scanner.nextLine`, it does not pass the value to my `setter` method, and the line is skipped.

Comment: Can you provide a sample input e.g. `abc $` - can it be a correct input?

Comment: @Alexander - I've updated the answer based on this clarification. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: The problem is that when I use `Scanner.nextLine`, it doesn't allow me to input the value that is passed to the setter method. Instead, the method works with the default currency value, and the line is skipped again. However, when using `Scanner.next`, it takes only the first word.

Comment: By the way, your regex does not allow more than two values. Could you please modify it so that I can enter more values?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
.matches("^(?:\\p{Sc}|\\p{L}+)(?:\\s*(?:\\p{Sc}|\\p{L}+))*$")
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/3tJjST/2). It matches a word or a currency symbol and then zero or more repetitions of zero or more whitespace characters and currency symbol / word.